# How to visualize an externally calculated FEM solution

Tags: plotting, finite-element-method, mesh, animation

I am trying to make animations of results of a FEM solver from an external model. Basically, I am pre- and post-processing in MMA. As a simple example, let's say I have a mesh such as:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{0., 0.}, {1., 0.}, {2., 0.}, {2., 1.}, {1., 
      1.}, {0., 1.}}, 
   "MeshElements" -> {TriangleElement[{{1, 2, 5}, {5, 6, 1}, {2, 3, 
        4}, {4, 5, 2}}]}];
Show[mesh[
  "Wireframe"[
   "MeshElementStyle" -> {Directive[FaceForm[Green]], 
     Directive[FaceForm[Red]]}]], 
 mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElementIDStyle" -> Red]], 
 mesh["Wireframe"["MeshElement" -> "PointElements", 
   "MeshElementIDStyle" -> Blue]]]
```

[image]

And let's say the solution for each element would be `f[i_,t_]:=Sin[ i t]` where `i` is the element id and `t` is time. Now I need to make the `FaceForm[]` work with color data. I can create a list of colors for element 1 for example with `Table[ColorData["TemperatureMap"][Sin[t]], {ii, Length[First@First@mesh["MeshElements"]]}, {t, 0, 10, 0.1}]`. But how do I bring it all together and make each element read the color from its solution function `f[i]` to be able to animate later?

Comment: What equations are you solving that the current FEM solver can not solve?

Comment: @user21 It's not that it cannot be solved, I've been assigned a task to make simulations with a model that another research group we are collaborating with have created (very large model which took them more than a decade to develop). The pre and post processing has been patchy based on who has been working on it and is a combination of Fortran, C, Bash, Perl, Python and some commercial software. I realized I can do almost all those in MMA very quickly. But I won't be able to reproduce their whole model easily.

Comment: @user21 also, you've been so great with your help all across the website (and I assume for Wolfram), I would definitely tell you what model/equations I am working on. I just don't want to mention it in searchable forums just to be safe.

Comment: Sure I understand, I was just curious of what the usage scenario is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an example of this on the [ElementMeshInterpolation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ElementMeshInterpolation.html#878064024) ref page.

Here is how I'd do it. I'd use `ElementMeshInterpolation` for this:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
mesh = ToElementMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> {{0., 0.}, {1., 0.}, {2., 0.}, {2., 1.}, {1., 
      1.}, {0., 1.}}, 
   "MeshElements" -> {TriangleElement[{{1, 2, 5}, {5, 6, 1}, {2, 3, 
        4}, {4, 5, 2}}]}];

(* create example data  *)
f[X_, t_] := Sin[Total[X^2, {2}] t]
coords = mesh["Coordinates"];
exampleTimes = Range[0, 1, 0.1];
exampleValues = {f[coords, #]} & /@ exampleTimes;
```

Note the dimensions of the values:

```
Dimensions[exampleValues]
(*{11, 1, 6}*)
```

Create the interpolating function:

```
tif = ElementMeshInterpolation[{exampleTimes, mesh}, exampleValues]
```

Visualize:

```
Manipulate[Plot3D[tif[t, x, y], {x, y} \[Element] mesh], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had done something similar by creating interpolation of tables of coordinates and the solution values for each node,  didn't know this existed. I wish the FEM package functions would show up in the Wolfram website search easier...

Comment: @MathX, I share that sentiment about the FEM functionality not being findable - if you want to do me a favor, report this to the support. It sometimes helps if this is requested by customers.